# AspNet.Identity authentication on IIS 8 expired after few seconds/minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I use the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.0 and MVC 5.2.
I log in on the mvc site. The controllers with [Authorize] works fine for some time. It's like after executing a dozen of actions of different controllers, my authentication session gets lost, and the application redirects to login action. 
I get the 'error' before the 30 minutes I've set in the authorisation configuration.

The Startup.Auth has the folowing code, so the time out is 30 minutes.

```
Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
}
```

This app is published on a Windows 2012 server with IIS8. If I put the same code on a Windows 2008 R2, I don't have this problem.

I guess I have to change a setting in the IIs8, but I don't know which.

For information: I use the version 2.2.1 of the framework, so the 'remember me' bug should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The error on the server (shared hosting) was:

A worker process with process id of '7400' serving application pool
'xyz' has requested a recycle because it reached its virtual memory
limit.

So changes the limit to a larger number was the solution.